# Connection String null reference exception in other systems

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, connection-string

I need to set .dbml connection string because it's change itself after deploying.
I test many posts in google but no one works for me.
here that links I already test in my app.
[1. Setting Connection string in dbml files using Linq to SQL in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444801/setting-connection-string-in-dbml-files-using-linq-to-sql-in-visual-studio-2008?rq=1)
[2. Point connectionstring in dbml to app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139043/point-connectionstring-in-dbml-to-app-config)
in my app code, my connection string is

```
<add name="PureWater.Properties.Settings.purewaterConnectionS"
        connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=purewater;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

According to 1 and 2 abbove, I set .dbml connection none and left empty. Then I modify .dbml designer code. 
after that, I call data context (dbml) from other windows forms like this:

```
pureWaterCxtDataContext cxt = new pureWaterCxtDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PureWater.Properties.Settings.purewaterConnectionS"].ConnectionString);
```

Everything is ok and I don't have error on my own system but I get an error on other systems on `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` that it is a null reference. This is very odd and can't trace exe file in other system to get what's happening?

**Thanks in advance for your help**

**Update:**
my app.config file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="PureWater.Properties.Settings.purewaterConnectionS"
             connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=purewaterPartovi; Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does your .config file have the name of the EXE.config?

Comment: No it's a windows form application and there is only app.config file

Comment: So, on the other PC, there is no `something.exe.config` , only `app.config`?

Comment: sorry I have it and it's exactly like my app.config in both release and debug folders. plus I publish my app with advanced installer so I copy this file in there.

Comment: Could you post the full config file?

Comment: I puted app.config on updated post